# Linear independence of standard basis vectors from Vandermonde style vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it true a statement that
**all** $n$ dimensional vectors of the standard basis (e.g. $[1 \ 0 \ 0 \ ...]^T$,  $[0 \ 1 \ 0 \ ...]^T$ etc ..)  are linearly independent from the **set** of the $n-1$ vectors $v_k$ (dim. n)  of the form (*I would  call them [Vandermonde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) style  vectors*):

$[1  \ x_k \ x_k^2 \ ....\ x_k^{n-1}]^T$

where all $x_k$ are distinct non-zero numbers?
I.e. standard basis vectors don't belong to the subspace generated by these $(n-1)$  vectors  $v_k$..

Example for $n=3$, $x_1=2$, $x_2=3$:

$det{ 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 2^2 & 3^2 
\end{bmatrix}}$ = 6

so the vector $i$ is linearly independent from the remaining column vectors. The vectors $j$, $k$ are independent too, what can be easily checked.

Comment: Small remark: it's easy to see the answer is yes if the $x_i$'s are all $n$-roots of unity (because in the decomposition of the vectors $(1, 0, ..., 0)^T$, etc. in the full Vandermonde basis, all the vectors have nonzero coefficients, which are themselves n-roots of unity → https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Completeness). But this is a very specific case.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes for $e_1 = (1, 0, \ldots, 0)^T$. If you could write it as a combination $e_1 = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \lambda_k \, v_k$, the coefficients could not be all $0$. By using the projection onto the $(n-1)$ last factors (i.e. by forgetting the first coefficient), you would then obtain a nontrivial relation $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \lambda_k \widetilde v_k = 0$, where $\widetilde v_k = (x_k, x_k^2, \ldots, x_k^{n-1})$. This contradicts the fact that the $(\widetilde v_k)$ are a basis of $\mathbb C^{n-1}$, by a simple application of Vandermonde's determinant.

This argument also works for $e_n = (0,0,\ldots, 0, 1)^T$, but I still don't know the answer for $e_2, \ldots, e_{n-1}$.

For $2 \leq \ell \leq n-1$, you have corresponding vectors $v_k^{[\ell]} = (1, x_k, \ldots, x_k^{\ell-1}, x_k^{\ell+1}, \ldots, x_k^{n-1})^T$. For my argument to work, you have to answer the question:

> Do the $(v_k^{[\ell]})_{k=1}^{n-1}$ form a basis of $\mathbb C^{n-1}$?

In fact, this question is easily seen to be equivalent to yours. Note that it's also equivalent to wondering if a $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ minor of the Vandermonde determinant is always invertible. The answer to that must be known, but alas, not by me.

---

This last question has been asked [on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60938/is-any-n-1-times-n-1-submatrix-of-an-n-times-n-vandermonde-matrix-inver). The answer is not always yes: the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 & x \\  1 & 1 & x^2\end{pmatrix}$ always has a $2\times 2$-minor with $1$'s everywhere, so it should answer your question.

In fact, the counterexample you get is quite simple: if $x_1 = 1$ and $x_2 = -1$, we have $\frac{v_1 - v_2}2 = (0, 1, 0)^T$.

---

Sorry for the "train of thought"-style answer, I really edited the answer at the same time I understood the problem.

Comment: Ok, it's very interesting this counterexample, maybe only for positive distinct numbers there are no counterexamples, (or maybe to exclude +1 and -1 from possible values)...if you see something to improve do it without hesitation...

Comment: For two Vandemonde vectors we can calculate all needed 3 minors:
$ det_{e1}=x_1{x_2}(x_2-x_1), det_{e2}={x_2}^2-{x_1}^2=(x_2+x_1)(x_2-x_1), det_{e3}={x_2}-{x_1}$ so the only problem is when $x_1+x_2=0$.  For other distinct non-zero $ x_1,x_2$  the statement is true. It is interesting to calculate formulas for higher dimensions.